# Number of people who observed the act of Ishmail sacrifice

Tags: sacrifice, prophet-ibrahim, eid-ul-adha

When Prophet Ibrahim was going to sacrifice Ismail at the hilltop, were there any people/observers who watched the whole incident and saw the replacement of Ismail with a lamb sent from Allah SWT?

If not, then how come this incident came to be known by the rest of the people at that time?

Answer (score 0):

We know no details from the Quran.

The Quran does not mention the name of the son, but from the fact that Isaac is mentioned some verses later, some scholars suggested that it was Ismail who would have been sacrificed. But as this is not explicit, we may also assume that the Quran doesn't stand against the account of the Torah.

According to the Torah (Gen. 22), this event took place after Abraham had sent Hagar and Ismail away.
Before preparing the sacrifice, he left his companions behind and proceeded only with his son Isaac. God and His angel saw it as well.

Thus, there were two humans, Abraham and his son, who knew it and could relate the story. And the angel could tell the story as well.

Comment: "the angel could tell the story as well.", tell to whom? I want to know how this whole incident came to light among the common people. Any evidence for that?

Comment: The Quran states that God gave the Torah to Musa. Although (not only) Islamic scholars doubt that this concerns the entire Torah we know today, the possibility  that the stories of the ancient have been revealed by an angel like the Quran need not be excluded.

Comment: So you meant to say that from the incident till it was revealed in the Torah at the time of Musa, no one knew about this? For all those years, no one was aware of it.

Comment: I personally think that the Torah (the version we know) does not exclusively contain revelation to Musa but also earlier traditions and hadith. But I don't have more knowledge than anybody else, and other options exist.

Comment: So there was no proof or mention of this incident till it was revealed in the Quran, hmm.

Comment: It's mentionned in detail in the Torah, Bereshit 22 https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.22?lang=bi&aliyot=0